# Xcode can't load ejected and published expo app

Tags: react-native, expo

I have run expo publish and gotten the URL for my offline app, and then run expo eject to ExpoKit. However, when I try to run the project in the xcworkspace in Xcode, The simulator reads: "There was a problem loading the requested app", shows a snippet of the URL it was checking, and says that I need to be serving my project on Expo CLI.

Is there some step I’m missing? I have tried doing expo publish and then expo eject several times, and every time it tells me I still need to be serving my project through Expo CLI.

Also, I do not have an Apple Developer Account, which is why I am going through ExpoKit.